# Lost signing certificate - revoking current certificate?

Tags: iphone

I released an iPhone app - since then, my macbook hard drive died, and I hadn't backed up the signing certificate.

I see in the dev portal there's a way for us to revoke our current certificate. If I do that, will that make my current application already being sold, invalid? I don't plan on releasing any more updates for it, I just want it to sit up there and continue selling. I'd like to then create a new certificate so I can continue developing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revoking your certificate will cause your app to stop working.

You can re-download the certificate on Apple's developer website.

Comment: He probably didn't back up the keys to the certificate, so re-downloading the certificate won't do any good.

Comment: Yeah that's the problem - they keys are gone. So my only choices are to revoke the cert, generate a new one with new keys (will invalidate my existing apps on the market) or apply for another developer account altogether?